# How to convert object data type to float in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, object

I have a data frame wherein a column is of "object" data type. I use `pd.to_numeric()` with `errors = 'coerce'` to convert this to "float" data type.  However, the converted column appears as NaN for all entries. If I let `errors = 'ignore'`, none of the entries are converted to float. Is there something I am missing? The following is the code snippet:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['gender'],errors = 'coerce')
```

The column `df['gender']` comprises 'Male' and 'Female' entries.  I would like to convert these to 'float' data type.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_numeric` can only convert numeric-ish things. For example it can convert the string `'10'` into the number `10`, but it can't convert something like `'Male'` into a number.

---

Instead use [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['gender'] = pd.factorize(df['gender'])[0].astype(float)
```

Or [`Series.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.factorize.html):

```
df['gender'] = df['gender'].factorize()[0].astype(float)
```

The first element of `factorize` contains the integer codes, so then we convert them `astype(float`).

---

Or as you commented, [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) also works:

```
df['gender'] = df['gender'].map({'Male': 0, 'Female': 1}).astype(float)
```

Comment: Thank you!  One quick comment:  is this not the same as df.gender.replace({'Male': 1, 'Female': 0})?  Nonetheless, it works fine.

Comment: Yep `map` is also fine, just a bit more manual. I also added an explanation for why `to_numeric` doesn't work here.

Comment: There is something glaring with pd.factorize(). The NaN entries in a given column are converted to '-1'.  I tried including "na_sentinel=None", but it did not work. Doing so could be unfavorable in certain applications. Perhaps it is better to employ 'map' method, wherein NaN entries are retained and could be filled/replaced using imputation methods.

Comment: Good point if there are NaNs. In this case with only 2 categories + NaN, `map` would be simplest. If you had a ton of categories + NaN, you could `factorize` automatically and chain a `replace`, e.g. `pd.Series(df['gender'].factorize()[0]).replace(-1, np.nan)`.